# Eigenvalues from the eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

$T\colon\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a linear transformation such that $T^{3}(v)=T(v)$. I know the matrix $[T]$ in the canonical basis has trace and determinant both equal to zero.

Also
$$[T]=[Q][D][Q]^{1}$$
such that
$$[Q]=\begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{3} & -1/\sqrt{6} \\ 0 & 1/\sqrt{3} & -2/\sqrt{6} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{6} \end{bmatrix}$$
and surely, $[D]$ is a diagonal matrix.

I have to find the eigenvalues of $T$. I know its eigenvectors are the columns of $[Q]$. I tried making the matrix product above, but I think this is not the way - I believe there's some properties I don't know which make things easier.

Comment: $T^3(v) = T(v)$ implies $\lambda^3 = \lambda$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$. What does this tell you about the possible values of $\lambda$? How can you use the trace and determinant conditions to pin down the $\lambda$?

Comment: determinant $0$ suggests eigenvalue $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v $ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $T^3(v)=T(v)\iff \lambda^3v=\lambda v$. But then $\lambda\in\{-1,0,1\}$. Since both the sum and the product of the eigenvalues are $0$, then, unless $T$ is the null function, the only possibility is that one of the eigenvalues is $1$, another one is $-1$ and the third one is $0$.

Comment: Did you mean *eigenvalues* when you typed *vectors*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.